# Pass file containing values to modify less variables in the command line

Tags: css, command-line, less

I have a theme file ../styles/mytheme.less and I want to load it while compiling a less file in the command line, how do I include this?

Normal syntax is `lessc --js --modify-var="primaryColor"="#ffeeff" main.less compiled.css`

So in place of passing primary color, I would like to pass an entire less file of variables. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use a batch file maybe? (not sure if this is what you are looking for)

Comment: Hi Ben, not exactly what I am looking for. Figured there should be a way to just pass a file containing variables since the command has a flag "--modify-var" for that purpose. The docs don't show how to pass a file, maybe it just isn't enabled.

Comment: I see, sorry about that. I don't know how you would go about doing that either... Good luck though!

Comment: Hi @Ben, welcome to Stackoverflow! It's great that you are trying to help, but Stackoverflow has certain guidelines, which helps keeping it useful for everyone. I am sorry to say that your answer is not really helpful, since it is more of a general suggestion than a concrete solution. Maybe it would help if you read-up on the guidelines? Especially the section about good answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites -- Again, welcome and don't let this comment discourage you from participating in the future :)